# Does CyanogenMod support USB Host API?

Tags: android, usb, cyanogenmod

Does CyanogenMod support Android's [USB Host API](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/host.html)?

I mean the Host API for the programmer, not just the USB host mode.

Comment: Developer questions are off-topic here; migrating to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

That would depend on the kernel, the official USB host api would be governed by the latest kernel version 3, which some handsets do have them as stock (SGSIII), there are unofficial backports of the USB api to accomodate the running of Ice Cream Sandwich on older platforms notably ARMv6.

To quote from the Android's [developer](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/host.html) site:

> USB host mode is supported in Android 3.1 and higher.

Comment: I have few devices with original Android 3.0/4.0, running on 2.6 Kernel. They support USB Host API. What I am asking is does the APIs on CyanogenMod are the same as on original (device manufacturer's) APIs?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean "*with original Android 3.0/4.0*", are you referring to AOSP stock source? What handset do you have? Despite that, there's a chance I reckon, it was back-ported into 2.6 kernel by CM so cannot verify. Depends on what OEM's have implemented in there so its a wild guess...

Comment: "Original" meaning installed on my device by the manufacturer, in this case Motorola Xoom tablet or Acer Iconia A500. I would like to install CM on these devices but I'm not sure whether my software (which uses USB Host API) will still work.

Comment: Ahh Okie.. Best bet would be to get on to irc.freenode.net and pop into #cyanogenmod channel and ask directly there - you will get an answer much faster :)

Answer (score 0):

Rather obviously, this would depend on the specific version of cyanogenmod in question.

One would generally think though that a cyanogenmod release would have all of the features of the AOSP release on which it is based (and then some), subject to required electrical capability and kernel driver source availability on a particular device.